# lifetimes BetaGeoFitter model is not working, it gives ConvergenceError

Tags: python, data-modeling

I just wanted to apply BetaGeoFitter model to my dataframe as:

```
> df = summary_data_from_transaction_data(df,"COMPANY_ID","INVOICE_DATE","TOTAL_PRICE",include_first_transaction=True, observation_period_end= today_date, freq= "W")

> bgf = BetaGeoFitter(penalizer_coef=0.0)
> bgf.fit(df['frequency'], df['recency'], df['T'])
```

It gives the error below(last rows of the error because it's too long). I don't know where is the problem and what this error is telling. By the way, it gives the same error when I change it with a larger penalizer_coef. Can anyone help me to fix it?

```
C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\autograd\tracer.py:48: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in multiply
  return f_raw(*args, **kwargs)
C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\autograd\tracer.py:48: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in subtract
  return f_raw(*args, **kwargs)
C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\autograd\numpy\numpy_vjps.py:78: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  defvjp(anp.log,    lambda ans, x : lambda g: g / x)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ConvergenceError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [19], line 2
      1 bgf = BetaGeoFitter(penalizer_coef=0.0)
----> 2 bgf.fit(df['frequency'], df['recency'], df['T'])
      3 print(bgf)

File C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\lifetimes\fitters\beta_geo_fitter.py:137, in BetaGeoFitter.fit(self, frequency, recency, T, weights, initial_params, verbose, tol, index, **kwargs)
    134 scaled_recency = recency * self._scale
    135 scaled_T = T * self._scale
--> 137 log_params_, self._negative_log_likelihood_, self._hessian_ = self._fit(
    138     (frequency, scaled_recency, scaled_T, weights, self.penalizer_coef),
    139     initial_params,
    140     4,
    141     verbose,
    142     tol,
    143     **kwargs
    144 )
    146 self.params_ = pd.Series(np.exp(log_params_), index=["r", "alpha", "a", "b"])
    147 self.params_["alpha"] /= self._scale

File C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\lifetimes\fitters\__init__.py:115, in BaseFitter._fit(self, minimizing_function_args, initial_params, params_size, disp, tol, bounds, **kwargs)
    113     return output.x, output.fun, hessian_
    114 print(output)
--> 115 raise ConvergenceError(
    116     dedent(
    117         """
    118     The model did not converge. Try adding a larger penalizer to see if that helps convergence.
    119     """
    120     )
    121 )

ConvergenceError: 
The model did not converge. Try adding a larger penalizer to see if that helps convergence.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try grouping values together like it worked for me:
df_ = df.groupby(["frequency", "recency", "T"]).size().reset_index()

BetaGeoBetaBinomFitter().fit(df_['frequency'], df_['recency'], df_['T'], weights=df_[0])